# Are there more accurate terms for "class methods" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, terminology

Is there really such a thing as a "class method" in Ruby (which is sometimes regarded as the equivalent of a static method in other languages), or is it merely something that just happens to be a singleton method of an object of class `Class`?

If the latter, are there any more accurate terms for such methods that would still be understandable by the average Ruby developer?

Comment: _Class's methods_, perhaps? :)

Answer (score 2):

"Class method" is the correct term.

See http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/ for a good explanation.

Comment: The person who wrote the blog post doesn't describe Ruby's object model in full, so I suspect he doesn't really understand it himself. Also, there's a comment at the bottom by someone who says that class methods don't really exist.

Answer (score 0):

"Class method" is fine and will be well understood, but technically you are correct, it is simply an instance method defined on a `Class` instance (or one of its ancestors, potentially its singleton class).